# Zoom map and set colorbar horizontal in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly in python to draw a map. After drawing, I export to a png file.

[image]

Now I want to make the map bigger or zoom the map and set the colorbar horizontal and below the map. Could anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: looks like Vietnam... fundamentally once you have created a static image (png) there is no interaction.  if you keep it as a plotly figure (I'm assuming a choropleth mapbox) you can interactively zoom or programmatically zoom.  I'd recommend that you keep as plotly, export as html or last option export multiple png files with different zoom levels

Comment: when you say zoom the map do you mean the default zoom? if so, you could change that and then export to a png

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following and experiment with the parameters to zoom into the image. One drawback is that the colorbar could get zoomed too. But it is a good place to start.

```
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

Parameters:

t - Sets the top margin (in px); default=80

r - Sets the right margin (in px); default=80

b - Sets the bottom margin (in px); default=80

l - Sets the left margin (in px); default=80

References:

1. https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/
2. https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-margin